# How do I find $P(1< Z <2)$ for given problem?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Suppose  a value z of the continuous random variable Z is generated as follows:
First, a fair die is rolled.If the side of the die facing up has 1 or 2 dots, then z is drawn from a Unif(0,2) distribution;otherwise z is drawn from a Unif(1,4) distribution.
Now for such random variable Z how can you find a P(1<Z<2)??
I am just unable to comprehend what the Z random variable would even look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 1/3 chance the die rolls 1 or 2 dots (called "pips," incidentally), and then a 1/2 chance the variable is between $1$ and $2$.

There's a 2/3 chance the die rolls 3, 4, 5 or 6 pips, and then a $1/3$ chance the variable is between $1$ and $2$.

So....

Comment: So it should be: (1/3*1/2) + (2/3*1/4)?

Comment: Yep.  See why??.....

Comment: yes i think so too,that's what confused me.

Comment: Ooops... yes... 1/3.

Comment: Gosh... so not even an upvote?

Comment: I haven't got enough reputation to upvote ;_; Thanks a lot thooo!!

Comment: @Dan can probably click to accept, which would be appropriate. But I do have enough reputation, so (+1).